# Adding one line code to all html files via ftp

Tags: html, scripting, ftp

Basically I have a JavaScript file that I need to include on every html file. There are 10 different ftp's and each has more than 600 static html web pages. Is it possible for me to add the code to all of the headers of HTML files without downloading the whole content for each ftp and editing them. Maybe using some features of some software like FileZilla, or with some scripting. I do not have access to root and it is a windows hosting. I am trying to add the   line to the head.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head><script type="text/javascript" src="resizer.js"></script> 
</head>
 <body>
   sample body content
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sounds like a job for a php template. If you don't have php, you'll have to download and re-upload, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert with FTP but I doubt that this is possible. You could run a PHP script on the server to do the job or simply embed your script dynamically using another script that is already included everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it is not possible to edit files on remote server without downloading them (using FTP). You have to download them, edit and then put back. Ofcourse you can write a script for that but the edit has to be done locally.

If you really don't want to download them, you can write a server-side script to edit the files and run it by accessing its URL. This presumes that the FTPs are classic web hostings.